# Wordpress: Populate Contact Form 7 form with repeater data from Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've been using this PHP code since about 10 years back to populate my contact forms with dynamic ACF data. It's worked like a charm until I needed to update to PHP 8 and now Contact Form 7 can't send the form no more.

The configuration is a standard repeater field in Advanced Custom Fields which I call using `[radio about use_label_element data:radio-date]` in the form builder.

Then I use this code in functions.php

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_tag_data_option', function($data, $options, $args) {
    $data = [];
    foreach ($options as $option) {
        if ($option = 'radio-date') {
            $repeater = get_field($option);
            $items = array_map(function($item) {
                return $item['course-date-start'] . ' - ' . $item['course-date-end'] . ', ' . $item['course-date'];
            }, $repeater);
            $data = array_merge($data, $items);
        }
    }
    return $data;
}, 10, 3);
```

I've been spending the last few days trying to find an alternative way of doing the function but with no success. So I figured why not ask for help. I'm not 100% familiar with deprecated functions since PHP 8 rolled out, so chances are I'm using a function that is no longer available..

Also, the error I'm seeing in Contact Form 7 when trying to send the form doesn't give me any additional information. Just that the form could not be sent.

Happy for any guidance!

Comment: `if ($option = 'radio-date')` -> `if ($option == 'radio-date')`

Comment: Thanks, I've changed it but that didn't solve the issue above